# "The System is out of resources." - Android Studio building process

Tags: java, android, jvm, android-gradle-plugin, virtual-machine

While building one of my app through Android Studio 1.5, the compiler throws message that the System is out of resources. I didn't understand why its throwing the error, while it builds fine for other apps.

My machine is having ubuntu14 with 8 gb ram. So, memory is not going to be the issue.I also tried changing the vmoptions of studio:

-Xms256m

-Xmx4096m

-Xss1024k

-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Maybe issue is in java(jvm). Following is the stack trace thrown by the compiler :

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkType(Check.java:533)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr$ResultInfo.check(Attr.java:476)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.check(Attr.java:275)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitLiteral(Attr.java:3859)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral.accept(JCTree.java:2037)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribArgs(Attr.java:664)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1806)
at    com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3226)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1815)
at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:566)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3226)
```

Have anyone faced this kind of issue before?? Kindly help !!
I got stuck into this from almost 2 days.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Hello guys, kindly provide your suggestions for the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a bad recursive call (infinite recursion) somewhere in your code. The only solution is to examine it carefully.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214758/5922757) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will analyze the code for the bad recursion call.

Comment: Does your problem occur only during build, or after you run the application?

Comment: Yes, it appears only during run time. The compiler doesn't  throws any exception during rebuilding or cleaning the application.